# Nested Sorting NSArray

Tags: ios, sorting, nested, nsarray

I have this NSArray of NSDates, that I want sort in such a way, that the dates are descending, but the hours are ascending.

the sorted array would (paraphrased) look like:

```
{tomorrowMorning, tomorrowAfternoon, thisMorning, thisAfternoon, yesterdayMorning, yesterdayAfternoon}
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this.

Comment: Just write a sort comparison that sorts on the date if the dates are different and if the two dates are the same then sorts on the time.

Comment: @Paulw11 Well, yes, that I get. But I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: try  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extension to Date -

```
extension Date {

    public func dateWithZeroedTimeComponents() -> Date? {

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
        components.hour = 0
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0

        return calendar.date(from: components)
    }
}
```

Then use this sort code -

```
// example test data
let dates: [Date] = [Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -80060), Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30), Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -75000), Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30000), Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30060)]

let sortedDates = dates.sorted { (date1, date2) -> Bool in

    if let date1Zeroed = date1.dateWithZeroedTimeComponents(), let date2Zeroed = date2.dateWithZeroedTimeComponents() {

        // if same date, order by time ascending
        if date1Zeroed.compare(date2Zeroed) == .orderedSame {
            return date1.compare(date2) == .orderedAscending
        }
        // otherwise order by date descending
        return date1.compare(date2) == .orderedDescending
    }

    return true
}

print(sortedDates)
```

Result -
[2017-06-15 05:20:29 +0000, 2017-06-15 05:21:29 +0000, 2017-06-15 13:40:59 +0000, 2017-06-14 15:27:09 +0000, 2017-06-14 16:51:29 +0000]

I think this is what you want?

Comment: yes, thank you. I would need to do that in Obj-c, but this makes sense to me.