# Sort array of dates ascending and starting from today date

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, swift4

I have an array of dates (same current year but different month and day)

I'm trying to sort the dates ascending and starting with the next date closest to today.

How to do this ?

**EDIT :**

I'm trying with an array containing these dates :

```
let a = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2017, month: 6, day: 6).date
let b = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2017, month: 11, day: 9).date
let c = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2017, month: 12, day: 10).date
let d = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: 2017, month: 1, day: 22).date
```

The date today is 2017-09-25.
**The output should be in this order :**

```
2017-11-09  //b
2017-12-10  //c
2017-01-22  //d
2017-06-06  //a
```

Comment: The question is answered below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date

Comment: you did not understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let dates  = [a!,b!,c!,d!]
let sorted =  dates.map{ ( ($0 < Date() ? 1 : 0), $0) }.sorted(by:<).map{$1}
```

Comment: Wow it work pretty nice, it was tricky indeed, I will try to understand. Thx a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
let dateObjectsFiltered = dateObjects.filter ({ $0 > Date() })

let datesSorted = dateObjectsFiltered.sorted { return $0 < $1 }
print(datesSorted)

// DatesObj : [2017-11-08 08:00:00, 2017-10-08 08:15:00, 2017-09-08 08:15:00, 2017-10-02 08:30:00, 2017-10-02 06:30:00]
// output :   [2017-10-02 06:30:00, 2017-10-02 08:30:00, 2017-10-08 08:15:00, 2017-11-08 08:00:00]
```

Comment: if the date today is 2017-10-06, it will show the first element of array (2017-10-02) and it's wrong, thx but it don't work.

Comment: `($0 > Date()) ? true : false }` is the same as just` $0 > Date()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before like this:

```
let dates: [Date] = [
  Date.distantFuture,
  Date.distantPast,
  Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*1),
  Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*2),
  Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3),
  Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*1),
  Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*2),
  Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*3)
]

let referenceDate = Date()
let sortedDates = dates.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
  return abs(left.timeIntervalSince(referenceDate)) < abs(right.timeIntervalSince(referenceDate))
}
```

Comment: Remove the `abs`

Comment: They were sorted for the original question correctly (time away from a reference date / now); not the current ask tho. Accepted answer provides what's needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following will do the job:

```
dates.sorted(by: { $0.timeIntervalSinceNow < $1.timeIntervalSinceNow })
```

Comment: don't work because I have some positive and some negative timeinterval

Comment: @user3722523 So what?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

print("Dates:")
let dates: [Date] = [
    Date.distantFuture,
    Date.distantPast,
    Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*1),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*2),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*1),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*2),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*3)
]

dates.forEach{ print($0) }


let referenceDate = Date()

let sortedDates = dates.sorted {
    $0.timeIntervalSinceNow < $1.timeIntervalSinceNow
}

print("\r\nSorted dates:")
sortedDates.forEach{ print($0) }
```