# Displaying messages(Both sent and received) in accordance to timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been struggling with this for a few days already and I really need your kind help.
Currently, the sent messages are displayed first, all on the left of the view controller based on their timestamp before the received messages are displayed on the right of the view controller. However,I would like both messages sent and received to be ordered together based on timestamp so that it will resemble the real world. For example, John sent Peter a message at 9:30am "Hi", Peter would reply at 10am "I am good", John would sent Peter a message at 10:15 saying "that is good to hear". The sent messages are displayed  all on the left first before the received messages all on the right, however I want it to reflect the real world(timestamp for both received and sent).

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadPosts()
    loadPostsReceivedMessage()
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatCollectionViewCell    
     let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

       //Setup the messageReceived and messageSent
        if chats[indexPath.row].senderID == senderIDNumber {
        if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message{
            let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = 
      NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
            cell.messageSend.frame = CGRect(x:8,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
            cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
         //showOutgoingMessage(text: chats[indexPath.row].message)
    }
            cell.messageSend.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
        }
    else {
            cell.messageReceived.text = chats[indexPath.row].message
            let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message
            let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText!).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
            cell.messageReceived.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
            cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x:view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 30,y:0,width:estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 4, height:estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }
    return cell
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     if let chatsText = chats[indexPath.row].message {
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
        let options = 
      NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: chatsText).boundingRect(with: 
        size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : 
        UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 
            20)
          }

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
      }

      //Get Message sent
     func loadPosts() {
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
    chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!).whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for document in documents {
                let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
               // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
self.chats.append(chat)
print(self.chats)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
}
}


//Get message received

     func loadPostsReceivedMessage() {
    /* let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
     let ref = Database.database().reference()
     ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
     (snapshot) in
        if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let currentUser = dic["username"] as? String
            let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        } */
            let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", 
         descending: false)
            print("thecurrentreceiver"+senderString)
            print("thecurrentsender"+receiverIDNumber)
         chatsRef.whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: 
        senderString).whereField("sender", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    for document in documents {
                        let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                        let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? 
              String
                        let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? 
           String
                        let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                        // let conversationsCounter = document.data() 
       ["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                        guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                        guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
                        let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!,profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
                        print("whatisthemessage"+messageText!)
                        self.chats.append(chat)
                        print(self.chats)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of your loadPostsReceivedMessage() method add the following lines:

```
self.chats =  self.chats.images.sorted(by: { $0.timeStampString > $1.timeStampString })
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

This will sort your data. If all of the chats are backwards, change the > to a <

If this does not work, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38168791/6481734) to learn how to turn a string into a date.

Comment: For the LoadPosts and LoadPostsReceivedMessage, they are both individually already sorted by timeStamp respectively.However,they are not sorted together by timestamp.So all the receivedMessage appears on the left in ascending order,while the sendMessage appears on the right..But it should like in a real chat be like sorted together.

Comment: No it didnt.,it only sorts receivedMessage by timestamp but not together with sentMessage. So sentMessage are all displayed on the left of the screen and then followed by receivedMessage on the left,but it should be like alternate like in a real world chat where people talk to each other almsot simulatenously/Concurently

Comment: Did you go to the link and try the answer there?