# Sorting time strings (HH:mm) in ascending order in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to sort an array of times in ascending order from 00:00 -> 23:59 in Swift 4. My application doesn't have any reference to a calendar as its used to register alarm times with an external hardware clock as a very basic alarm that simply goes from 00:00 -> 23:59 then wraps.

Not sure if this is the best approach, but i've tried the following code based on [Sort Objects in Array by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date) 
but I can't get it to work with just time only. The (date) object fails to initialise. It doesn't like the (dateStyle) and (timeStyle) changes from the initial example. Code is below:

```
let testArray = ["23:59", "01:23", "18:23", "04:42", "00:00"]
  var convertedArray: [Date] = []

  var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
  dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

  for dat in testArray {
     let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)
     if let date = date {
        convertedArray.append(date)
     }
  }

  var ready = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending })

  print(ready)
```

When working the print function should print the sorted array in the following order:

[00:00, 01:23, 04:42, 18:23, 23:59]

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert the strings into dates. Just sort the strings as numbers.

```
let testArray = ["23:59", "01:23", "18:23", "04:42", "00:00"]
let sortedArray = testArray.sorted { $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
print(sortedArray)
```

Output:

> ["00:00", "01:23", "04:42", "18:23", "23:59"]

As it turns out, since each of your time strings are in a nice fixed format of `HH:mm`, you don't even need to use `localizedStandardCompare`. You get the desired results with:

```
let sortedArray = testArray.sorted()
```

This only works since you have only numbers and because the numbers are padded with leading zeros. If either of those cases weren't there you would need the first option.

Comment: Or just `testArray.sorted()` if all strings have the same fixed format.

Comment: @MartinR Lol. Sometimes the obvious is too obvious.

Comment: Brilliant @rmaddy!, much cleaner approach and one line solution. Thank you.