# how to fetch last n records in CoreData using fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table Student which has two attributes Name and DateOfBirth.
I want to display names of students in a UITableView in descending order of their DateOfBirth that is younger one on top and older on bottom of the list.

I have created a FetchRequest that fetches all the students and displays in descending order of their DateOfBirth.

```
let studentFetchRequest = Student.fetchRequest()
let dateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Student.dateOfBirth), ascending: false)
studentFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSortDescriptor]

let frc = NSFetchedResultsController<Student>(fetchRequest: studentFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

frc.performFetch()
```

Now, I have a requirement that I need to display only last 15 students. Considering Student table has 50 records.

I tried changing the sortDescriptor's ascending property to true and added fetchLimit of 15 to my studentFetchRequest to fetch only last 15 students.

It fetches the last 15 students but it reverses the order in which they are being listed in UITableView. i.e. older students on top and younger on the bottom.

How can I modify the fetchRequest and still be able to use a FetchedResultsController to display the last 15 students in my `UITableView`?

I need to use FetchedResultsController because the actual table is far complex, I have simplified the question to explain the situation.

Comment: Add a new attribute with Date.

Comment: @ElTomato, I couldn't get you.

Comment: Refer this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date

Comment: @Saurabh This doesn't solve my problem. I know the way to fetch all the objects and sort it in reverse but I want to use it with FetchedResultsController. FetchedResultsController fetches the objects based on the fetchRequest. I can't sort it after the objects have been fetched.

Comment: if your fetched date is in String format then you need to convert that to Date format and then sort that array.

Comment: I would follow the approach you started - change the sort descriptor to ascending and add the fetchLimit - but then modify the tableView datasource methods to **display** them in reverse order.  You can do this just by changing the index used to obtain the FRC object for each row: ie. rather than using `row` use `15-row`.