# how to sort data from json according to date and sum nominal by date in swift?

Tags: json, swift, sorting, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to sort the data from the json array according to the date,
and the nominal amount of data that matches the date. I use swiftyjson and alamofire.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

    class HomeViewController: UIViewController{
          override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
             fetchData()

             let createOrder = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "createOrder")
             let nominal = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "nominal")

             createOrder = createOrder?.sorted{ $0 < $1 } 
             print(createOrder?.description)
           }
         }

    func fetchData(){
            let url = ""

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON{
                (response) in
                switch response.result {

                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)

                    let jsonData = json["data"]["transaction"]

                    let data = jsonData.arrayValue.map{ $0["nominal"].string}
                    let createOrder = jsonData.arrayValue.map { $0["order_created"].string}

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "nominal")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(createOrder, forKey: "createOrder")

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

here is response JSON

```
"data" : {
    "transaction" : [

{
    "order_created" : "2019-03-30 14:39:05",
    "nominal" : "300000",
},
{
    "order_created" : "2019-03-30 11:26:08",
    "nominal" : "250000",
},
{
    "order_created" : "2019-03-29 10:49:44",
    "nominal" : "200000",
}
]
```

what has been achieved:

```
Optional("[\"2019-03-30 10:49:44\", \"2019-03-30 11:26:08\", \"2019-03-30 14:39:05\"]")
```

i get data on 2019-03-30 are 2 nominal 300000 and 250000

in 2019-03-29 i get 1 nominal 200000

i want total nominal on 2019-03-30 are 300000 + 250000 = 550000

so the result should i get:
on 2019-03-30 total is 500000
and 2019-03-29 total is 200000

please help me

Comment: I think u need to group the date, and then get total nominal for each date. For grouping the date, you can refer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Codable` instead of `SwiftyJSON` as it's more explicitly typed but answering your question directly in regards to `SwiftyJSON` you could go with this:

```
func processedTransactions(_ transactions: JSON) -> [(date: String, nominal: Double)] {
    let processedTransactions = transactions
        .arrayValue
        .reduce(into: [String: Double]()) { (r, t) in
            if let date = t["order_created"].stringValue.split(separator: " ").first {
                let date = String(date)
                r[date] = r[date, default: 0] + (Double(t["nominal"].stringValue) ?? 0)
            }
        }
        .sorted { $0.key > $1.key }
        .map { (date: $0.key, nominal: $0.value) }

    return processedTransactions
}

func handleProcessedTransactions(_ transactions: [(date: String, nominal: Double)]) {
    //do something with your sorted transactions
    for t in transactions {
        print(t.date, t.nominal)
    }
}
```

Here, in `processedTransactions(_:)`, we basically iterate through the dates and prepare unique entries based on just `YYYY-DD-MM` part.
Simultaneously we keep an account of the total sum of nominal value relating to a particular date.
This is done in the `reduce` part (*The logic I have used is basic string manipulation but it can be argued that it's error pront so feel free to  rewrite that part*)
Then we `sort` it and just for better readability, we `map` to recreate the object as tuples `(date: String, nominal: String)`
We can then pass this to `handleProcessedTransactions(_:)` and operate required logic on it.

---

Also, you seem to be using `UserDefaults` so this is what the existing part of your code can look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()

    let json = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "transactions")
    let transactions = processedTransactions(JSON(json))
    handleProcessedTransactions(transactions)
}

func fetchData() {
    let url = ""
    Alamofire
        .request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                let transactionJSON = json["data"]["transaction"]
                UserDefaults.standard.set(transactionJSON.arrayObject, forKey: "transactions")

                //you probably want to handle it here too
                let transactions = self.processedTransactions(transactionJSON)
                self.handleProcessedTransactions(transactions)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** Why you use `SwiftyJSON`  and there is built in `Codable protocol` ? [Tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/swift-4-decoding-json-codable/)

**Second** : The idea is to group your data by  `yyyy-MM-dd`  like that `2019-03-30` this will require more work . i create the decodable version for  your response you can check

```
import Foundation

struct JsonData: Decodable {
    let data: Transactions
}
struct Transactions: Decodable {
    let transaction: [Transaction]
}

struct Transaction: Decodable {
    let nominal: String
    let orderCreated : Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orderCreated = "order_created"
        case nominal
    }
}

extension JsonData {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try DatedDecoder().decode(JsonData.self, from: data)
    }
}

fileprivate func DatedDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.yyyyMMddHHmmss)
    return decoder
}


extension DateFormatter {


    // for modeling json data
    static let yyyyMMddHHmmss : DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return dateFormater
    }()

    // for grouping
    static let yyyyMMdd: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return dateFormater
    }()
}
```

And you can use like that

```
 // (data) is response of your API call

 if let jsonData = try? JsonData(data: data){

            let predicate: (Transaction) -> String = { transaction in
                return DateFormatter.yyyyMMdd.string(from: transaction.orderCreated)
            }

            let groupingByDate : [String:[Transaction]] = Dictionary(grouping: jsonData.data.transaction, by: predicate)

            let items =  groupingByDate.map { item -> (date:String , value:Int) in
               return (item.key , item.value.map({Int(String($0.nominal))!}).reduce(0, +))
            }
            //  Final Items array is tuple with date and total nominal  [(date: "2019-03-30", value: 550000), (date: "2019-03-29", value: 200000)
            print(items)
        }
```

Json API Response  for above solution

```
{
    "data" : {
        "transaction" : [

            {
                "order_created" : "2019-03-30 14:39:05",
                "nominal" : "300000"
            },
            {
                "order_created" : "2019-03-30 11:26:08",
                "nominal" : "250000"
            },
            {
                "order_created" : "2019-03-29 10:49:44",
                "nominal" : "200000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```