# Sorting an array of (string) dates

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array, **workoutData**, of string dates in the format *EEEE, d MMM, yyyy* so the dates are saved as *Tuesday, 30 Apr, 2019*, *Thursday, 25 Apr, 2019* and *Saturday, 27 Apr, 2019*  etc. I have tried using the *sorted(by:)* method below however this orders the dates alphabetically.

```
let orderedArray = self.workoutData.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending})
```

How can I order this array in a descending order by date? I would like to keep the individual dates as strings and I am using these to populate a tableView.

Excuse the lack of experience. Thanks

Comment: Use a `(NS)DateFormatter` to interpret the Date String as Date and then sort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date

Comment: FYI - you should convert those strings to `Date` once when loading the data. Don't keep the strings around. This will make all future processing much more efficient. This includes sorting and later showing those dates to users in the proper format for their locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create `DateFormatter` with certain `Locale` and `DateFormat` which you need

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d MMM, yyyy"
```

Then you can sort your `String` array like this: You create `Date` from `String` using `DateFormatter` and then you just sort two `Date` values

```
let ordered = workoutData.sorted { string1, string2 in
    guard let date1 = formatter.date(from: string1), let date2 = formatter.date(from: string2) else { return false }
    return date1 < date2
}
```