# Sort Arrays based on Month and Year String

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter, array-filter

What is the best way to sort an Array which Contains a month and Year in the following format:

```
let dateX2 = Date(); let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
formatter2.dateFormat = "MMMM,,yyyy"
let dateZ = formatter2.string(from: dateX2)
```

Array containing the above formatted dates not in correct order:

```
let array = ["July,,2019", "January,,2020", "February,,2019", "March,,2020"]
```

Expected result following sorting:

```
let result = ["February,,2019", "July,,2019", "January,,2020", "March,,2020"]
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using and sorting on the original Date object instead?

Comment: `let sorted = array.sorted(by: { formatter.date(from: $0) ?? Date() < formatter.date(from: $1) ?? Date() })` this does the trick.

Comment: The best way to sort a `Date` array only by year and month is with [compare(_:to:toGranularity:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293166-compare) of `Calendar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of Date objects instead as your data source and then sort and format the dates to your expected output

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM,,yyyy"

let sortedArry = array.sorted(by: {$0 < $1}).map {formatter.string(from: $0)}
```

Example input

```
let oneMonth = 3600 * 24 * 30.5 //I know :) but its just to generate som test data
let array = [
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -9 * oneMonth),
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -3 * oneMonth),
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -4 * oneMonth),
    Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -10 * oneMonth),
]
```

gives

> ["October,,2019", "November,,2019", "April,,2020", "May,,2020"]

Comment: I see what you mean, I get: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: Not sure what you refer to, there is no conversion from string to date in the code.

Comment: I get that error for the “let sortedArray =“ line My array is a [String] format, is that why?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully, it says you should have an array of Date objects that is `var array: [Date]`

Answer (score 0):

To sort date strings you'll need to convert them to `Date` objects. Given that your sample code starts out with date objects, you'd be much better off leaving them as Date objects in the first place.

Some of the other responders suggest sorting using calls to `DateFormatter.date(from:)` in the body of the sort closure. Note that doing that is REALLY slow. (It's > 1000x slower than sorting date objects directly.) If you're sorting more than a few dates, it's better to combine the date strings into tuples with the original date string and a Date object, sort the tuples, and then extract the date strings from the sorted array of tuples.

See my answer in [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51663558/205185), where I show a couple of different ways of sorting structures that contain date strings.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to sort it as per your examples.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should accept it, or whichever other answer provided the best solution. That is a strong norm on this site. Up-votes of helpful answers are also encouraged, but not required.