# How can I sort two different dates?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, time

How can I sort two different dates?
Do I need to use an array for this?
I could not run these codes.

```
let testArray = ["25 Temmuz 2016", "30 Temmuz 2016"]
var convertedArray: [Date] = []

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"// yyyy-MM-dd"

for dat in testArray {
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dat)
    if let date = date {
        convertedArray.append(date)
    }
}

var ready = convertedArray.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending })

print(ready)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Objects in Array by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168594/sort-objects-in-array-by-date)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's in `convertedArray`? What's the output? Identifying where lies the issue is a big step: Is the String -> Date? Is the sort? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the correct Locale if you're parsing localised dates.

Try the following (I assumed you're using the Turkish locale):

```
let testArray = ["25 Temmuz 2016", "30 Temmuz 2016"]

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "tr_TR")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

let convertedArray = testArray
    .compactMap(dateFormatter.date)
    .sorted(by: >)

print(convertedArray)
```

---

According to the LeoDabus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/8697793), if there is a daylight savings transition you may also need to specify the Calendar:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
```

Comment: Why UTC TimeZone?

Comment: Btw `compactMap(dateFormatter.date)`

Comment: Why would you parse a date in a different timezone? Note that this might fail also if you don't set the dateFormatter calendar property if you try to parse a daylight transition date. Regarding "2016-07-24 23:00:00 +0000" this is UTC time representation not local time. If you use a dateFormatter to display it it will display the proper day.

Comment: "But for sorting it shouldn't really matter" it does matter. The result is an array of dates parsed incorrectly unless you are sure the date string represents UTC timezone which is very unlikely without the timezone explicitly stated in the string (+0000, +00:00 or Z).

Comment: `let convertedArray = testArray.sorted { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) ?? .distantPast > dateFormatter.date(from: $1) ?? .distantPast }` and remove the UTC timezone

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, I thought of another answer when I said that sorting doesn't matter. Here obviously it *does*. And thanks for the UTC explanation - I removed the unnecessary TimeZone.

Comment: Don't forget to check the link I have posted above regarding the absence of the time in the string and setting a calendar

Comment: @LeoDabus I've checked it and for me it works without setting a calendar. I just don't understand why setting a calendar may be necessary in some (which?) cases or Locales.

Comment: Just where there is daylight savings transition. It depends on the location. For example here in Brazil it used to have until 2017 but not anymore. Not so simple. It also depends if the transition occurs at the beginning of the day

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, makes sense - thanks for all your explanations.